# Setting up a reverse connection for remote code development with Eclipse

Tags: firewall, eclipse, remote

I am using Nvidia Nsight 10.2 which, under the hood, ships Eclipse Platform version 4.4.0. I would like to develop CUDA code remotely on a target following the broad lines of https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/remote-development-using-a-firewalled-target/129131

However, unlike that blog, my target is a cluster node tightly firewalled behind a log-in node. For example, I managed to get ParaView set up a reverse connection and it works, for the target/server does ping the host/client.

Seen that Nsight is widely based on Eclipse, I wondered whether it is possible to set up a reverse connection with Eclipse, and how to do that. Thanks for any advice.

The OS is (flavours of) Linux in all machines involved.